# SqlAlchemy: How to make a LONGBLOB column in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy with mysql-python, I have this table:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Index, LargeBinary
Base = declarative_base()
class Tbl(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'tbl'
     ...
     data = Column(LargeBinary())
```

However, when I create this table (using `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`), and then `DESCRIBE tbl;` in mysql, I get this:

```
mysql> describe logs;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
...
| data         | blob        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Expected result: I want this to be a `longblob` in mysql, and not a `blob` which is limited to 64kB

Comment: The MySQL dialect includes a [`LONGBLOB`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.LONGBLOB) type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using:

```
data = Column(LargeBinary(length=(2**32)-1))
```

Causes LargeBinary to create a `longblob` type

Comment: using flask-sqlalchemy models and mysql, this was the way to go for me. if i left it as ```LargeBinary``` without specifying the length it defaulted to ```blob``` in mysql (64kb).

Answer (score 5):

As the developer's response to the error report 
[LargeBinary type fails to create LongBlob in Mysql and creates Blob](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3883/largebinary-type-fails-to-create-longblob) points out:

> If your issue is just being able to render LONGBLOB, as opposed to
>   disagreement over LargeBinary's default of BLOB, you can of course use
>   the sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.LONGBLOB type directly. If you want to
>   combine this with generic LargeBinary you can use
>   LargeBinary().with_variant(LONGBLOB, "mysql")